# terminator terminal resize

Tags: command-line, resize, terminator

I set up the terminator terminal to the quake drop down mode; however, the terminal is only 90x25.  I would like for it drop down the whole width of the screen but not full screen.  When the terminal isn't in the drop down mode, I can resize it manually but it won't let me do that now.  How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you have `~/.config/terminator/config`. It seems to have a lot of possibilities. I don't use terminator myself but came across http://bytefreaks.net/howtos/howto-make-terminator-terminal-act-like-guake-terminal-in-ubuntu-11-10. Maybe some of it is applicable to 12.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a 1366x768 monitor, here is what I set to achieve a full screen width and about half way with the terminator terminal.

```
gedit ~/.config/terminator/config


[global_config]
enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
hide_from_taskbar = True
always_on_top = True
tab_position = bottom
sticky = True
[keybindings]
hide_window = F12
[profiles]
[[default]]
background_darkness = 0.8
palette = "#000000:#cc0000:#4e9a06:#c4a000:#3465a4:#75507b:#06989a:#d3d7cf:#555753:#ef2929:#8ae234:#fce94f:#729fcf:#ad7fa8:#34e2e2:#eeeeec"
background_type = transparent
foreground_color = "#00ff00"
[layouts]
[[default]]
[[[child0]]]
  position = 0:24
  type = Window
  order = 0
  parent = ""
  size = 1650, 464
[[[terminal3]]]
  profile = default
  type = Terminal
  order = 1
  parent = child0
[[[terminal2]]]
  profile = default
  type = Terminal
  order = 0
  parent = child0
[plugins]
```